# Array with fixed interval size

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(array_chunk($input_array, 2));
?>
```

This example from php manual will output this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

)
```

But i need to have an interval with fixed size. So the last value should be:

```
 [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
            [1] => null
        )
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$size = 3;
$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');

$result = array_chunk(
    array_merge(
        $input_array, 
        ((count($input_array) % $size) == 0) 
            ? array()
            : array_fill(
                  0,
                  $size - (count($input_array) % $size), 
                  NULL
              )
    ), 
    $size
);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the best practice, but it's how I would do it.

```
<?php
function arr_chunk($input_array, $chunk_size, $fixed=null) {
    if (is_null($fixed)) {
        $fixed = $chunk_size;
    }
    $chunked = array_chunk($input_array, $chunk_size);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($chunked); $i++) {
        while (count($chunked[$i]) < $fixed) {
            $chunked[$i][] = null;
        }
    }
    return $chunked;
}

$input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
print_r(arr_chunk($input_array, 2));
?>
```

Where `arr_array` takes `$fixed` as an additional argument, or is set to `$chunk_size` giving all array chunks the same length.